# wordpress - What are the valid values of 'std' for 'List Item' option tree type?

Tags: wordpress

I want to have a default value (`'std'`) for a `list-item` type. I know how to set `std` for types other than `list-item`. Here's an example:

```
array(
    'id'          => 'logo',
    'label'       => 'Logo',
    'std'         => OT_URL.'others/logo@2x.png', // This is std for upload type.
    'type'        => 'upload',
),
array(
    'id'          => 'regions-page',
    'label'       => 'Default Page Widgets Area',
    'std'         => 'right', // This is std for radio-image type.
    'type'        => 'radio',
    'choices'     => array(
        array(
            'value'       => 'right',
            'label'       => 'Region 2',
        ),
        array(
            'value'       => 'left',
            'label'       => 'Region 3',
        ),
    )
```

For types like `radio` and `select` there are some `choices` which `std` may refer to one of their `value`s. `list-item` type has something like `choices` called `settings`. Here's an example of `list-item` type:

```
array(
    'id'          => 'home-ads-items',
    'label'       => 'Add ADS. banner under Featured Products',
    'std'         => '', // I want to set this in order to Image setting would be its default.
    'type'        => 'list-item',
    'settings'    => array(
        array(
            'id'      => 'img',
            'label'   => 'Image',
            'std'     => '',
            'type'    => 'upload',
            'class'   => '',
            'choices' => array()
        ),
        ...
```

I want to set `std` in order to have `Image` as default value. But I don't know how.

Comment: Just set as 'std' => array('id'=>'xx','label'=>'dfd');

Comment: No, it didn't work. Nothing happened.

Comment: Are you talking about the STD in the 'settings' or in the first level array ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be fairly simple actually. I'm assuming you have the latest version (2.2.0), I don't know if it works in lower versions.

So, consider this configuration:

```
'id'        => 'colors',
'section'   => 'colors',
'label'     => 'Colors',
'type'      => 'list-item',
'settings'  => array(
    array(
        'id'        => 'color',
        'label'     => 'Color',
        'type'      => 'colorpicker',
    ),
),
```

Now, we want to have two default colors, white and black. Simply add two arrays in the `std` option, and use `id`'s as keys. So, we add:

```
'std'       => array(
    array('title' => 'White', 'color' => '#ffffff'),
    array('title' => 'Black', 'color' => '#000000'),
),
```

That's it. You'll have two predefined colors. As you can see, we don't have a configured `list-item` item with `id` `title`, but it's still present, because that's a default entry available to each option.